# jquery validate for my login page is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am very new to jquery & javascript working on login page where Iam using simple jquery validation code. To check whether my username as **john** and the password **pass** if it was correct it has to redirect to other page. Else I need to show an error message.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#form1").validate({
               debug: false,
               rules: {
                   name: "required",
                   password: {
                       required: true,
                       minlength: 8
                   }
               },
               messages: {
                   name: "Please enter your name.",
                   password: "Please enter 8 letters minimum.",
               }
           });

       });
   </script>
```

The above code was checking the first rule where if it is empty or not but this itself not working. I am not getting any error label message.

Here is the fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/2257chwq/4/)

Thanks in advance

Regards
M

Comment: Can you please provide your HTML please?

Comment: Just now I have added fiddle link

Comment: The fiddle's link is not working for me right now.

Comment: I can't find the `form` tag here http://jsfiddle.net/2257chwq/

Comment: @webNeat kindly check again in http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/2257chwq/4/

Comment: It's due to your HTML not having name properties. Take a look at the sample I made below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in your HTML. validate binds properties by their name. Your inputs only have ids and no names. [Take a look at my sample (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/5RrGa/1050/). It performs correctly. You also had mismatching formId on your jquery validate method.

As stated in the comments I also added the external resource to the fiddle (.validate jquery plugin)

**Html**

```
<h1>Form Validation Example</h1>
<form id='form1' name='form1' method='post' action='' >   <p>
   Name: <input type='text' name='name' id='name' class='required' />
   </p>
   <p>
   Email: <input type='text' name='password' id='password' class='required' />
   </p>
   <p>
   <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
   </p>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#form1").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            name: "required",
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: "Please enter your name.",
            password: "Please enter 8 letters minimum.",
        }
    });


  });
```

Comment: Also take note in this answer the external resource was added to the fiddle (.validate jquery plugin). Nice fix.

Comment: thank you so much @PaulBinder Can you please guide me how to if i login correct it has to redirect to other page